# Is there an effect for the eigenvalues on vectors other than the Eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does having an eigenvalue greater than one mean that the magnitude of any vector multiplied by the matrix will be increased?

Comment: Should the question read "Does having *all* eigenvalues greater than one..."? If the edit made by Andrew Whelan is correct, it is false, as shown by the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

What about $\textbf{A}:=\begin{bmatrix}8&12\\-3&-4\end{bmatrix}$?  This matrix has only one eigenvalue $2$, which is greater than $1$.  However, under the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the size of $\textbf{A}\,\textbf{u}$ is less than the size of $\textbf{u}$, if $\textbf{u}:=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\end{bmatrix}$.

You can even require that the matrix be diagonalizable, and the claim remain false.  Take $\textbf{A}:=\begin{bmatrix}-22&-40\\15&27\end{bmatrix}$ and $\textbf{u}:=\begin{bmatrix}16\\-9\end{bmatrix}$.  The eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$ are $2$ and $3$.  However, the size of $\textbf{A}\,\textbf{u}$ is less than that of $\textbf{u}$.

However, if you demand that the matrix be normal as well, then the claim is true.  That is, if $\textbf{A}$ is a complex $n$-by-$n$ normal matrix whose eigenvalues are complex numbers with moduli greater than $1$, then $\|\textbf{A}\,\textbf{u}\big\|\geq \|\textbf{u}\|$ for all $\textbf{u}\in\mathbb{C}^n$.  The equality holds if and only if $\textbf{u}$ is the zero vector.