# Given matrix $A$ such that $\forall x : |Ax| > |x|$, and eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. Show $|\lambda |\geq 1$.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say matrix $A$ has the property that for any non-zero vector $x$, left-multiplication of $x$ by $A$ increases the magnitude. That is, $\forall x$
$$
|x| > 0 \implies |Ax| > |x|
$$
Is it true that all the eigenvalues of $A$ must have magnitude greater than or equal to one?

A loose converse is true:  If all the eigenvalues are greater than $1$, then for all non-zero vectors, $|Ax| > |x|$.  And this has a nice goemetric interpretation, in terms of a unit sphere at the center of an ellipsoid with all semi-axes greater than one.

I have tried to prove that all the eigenvalues are greater than one in magnitude by decomposing $x$ in terms of the eigenvectors, but got lost, among other things, in the cases of multiple equal eigenvalues.

Anybody got a proof?

Comment: Related to your converse: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867823/is-there-an-effect-for-the-eigenvalues-on-vectors-other-than-the-eigenvectors

Comment: I may be missing something, but if $A$ had an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|\leq 1$, couldn't we just look at an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ to get a contradiction?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with associated eigenvector $x\neq0$.  Then we have
$$|\lambda|\cdot|x|=|\lambda x|=|Ax|>|x|, $$
and thus
$$|\lambda|>1.$$
Since the eigenvalue $\lambda$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $|\lambda|>1$ *for all* eigenvalues of $A$